# React native firebase storage async/wait not waiting

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, async-await, firebase-storage

```
    export async function getImage(key){
        let url = '';
        try{
          const imageRef = storage().ref(key)
          url = await imageRef.getDownloadURL();
        }catch(e){ console.log(e)}
        return url;
    }
```

then...in the call

```
   imageUrl='';
   getImage(email).then((url) => { 
      imageUrl = url
      console.log('imageUrl1:',imageUrl);
   })

   console.log('imageUrl2:',imageUrl);
```

result:

imageUrl2:

imageUrl1:url:https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/.....

I expected first the log of imageUrl1....

Answer (score 0):

```
   getImage(email).then((url) => { 
      imageUrl = url
      console.log('imageUrl1:',imageUrl);
   })
```

.then will always run after the getImage() is executed. That would mean your imageUrl2 will run first in this case.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is expected in JavaScript, and has nothing to do with the Firebase SDK you're using.  In JavaScript, functions that return a promise are **asynchronous** and will return immediately, before the promise is fulfilled or rejected.  You should know that `then` also returns a promise asynchronously.  **It does not block the execution of your code or wait for the promise to become resolved.**  Your code will keep executing after any `then` or `catch`.

In your specific case, your second log line will print immediately with the initial empty string value of `imageUrl`.  The callback function you provide to `then` will be invoked **some time later**, after the promise returned by `getImage` is fulfilled with a value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
export async function getImage(key){
    let url = '';
    try{
      const imageRef = await storage().ref(key)
      url = await imageRef.getDownloadURL();
      return url;
    }catch(e){ 
      console.log(e)
     }      
 };

   const url = await getImage(email);
   console.log('imageUrl:',url);
```

Comment: Don't work --> Can not use keyword 'await' outside an async function. Thank's

Comment: thats right the parent must be an async function it must be inside an async function